# Prefixing a company name to URL in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.5.x and is working fine with default routing. Now, I'd like to prefix a company name parameter that will vary based on user logged in.

For instance, currently it works this way

```
http://localhost/Pages/view
http://localhost/Pages/add
```

I would like it to work this way

```
http://localhost/acme/Pages/view
http://localhost/acme/Pages/add
```

I have already configured routes.php configuration file to take care of the actual routing above with the following lines

```
/** 
 * Catch urls like http://www.domain.com/<company>/<controller>/<action>/<parameters> 
 */ 
    Router::connect( 
        '/:company/:controller/:action/*', 
        array (), 
        array ( 
            'company' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' // regular expression match for the company parameter 
        ) 
    ); 

/** 
 * Catch urls like http://www.domain.com/<company>/<controller>/<action> 
 */ 
    Router::connect( 
        '/:company/:controller/:action', 
        array (), 
        array ( 
            'company' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' // regular expression match for the company parameter 
        ) 
    );  

/** 
 * Catch urls like http://www.domain.com/<company>/<controller>/ 
 */ 
    Router::connect( 
        '/:company/:controller', 
        array (
            'action' => 'index'
        ), 
        array ( 
            'company' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' // regular expression match for the company parameter 
        ) 
    ); 

/** 
 * Catch urls like http://www.domain.com/<company>/ 
 */ 
    Router::connect( 
        '/:company', 
        array( 
            'controller' => 'Users', // default controller 
            'action' => 'index' // default action 
        ), 
        array ( 
            'company' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' // regular expression match for the company parameter 
        ) 
    );
```

The problem I have is that in many places in my application I have used `echo Router::url('')` and now all those links will need to be updated. Is there some universal way that I can ensure that once a user is logged in, all links generated for that user will obtain the relevant company name and prefix with that?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: go to core.php and add this line Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('acme'));

Comment: go to your controller and add function such as public function pages_dashboard(){}

Comment: and view the name should be pages_dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `persist` option, it defines which parameters that are present in the current URL should automatically be included when generating new URLs.

**Example:**

```
Router::connect( 
    '/:company/:controller/:action/*', 
    array (), 
    array ( 
        'company' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
        'persist' => array(
            'company'
        )
    ) 
);
```

In case the current URL is `/acme/pages/view`, the following call

```
Router::url(array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'add'
));
```

would generate a URL including the company name like

```
/acme/pages/add
```

Likewise the company name would not be included in case it's not present in the current URL, ie on `/pages/view` the generated URL would be

```
/pages/add
```

In case you need to include the company name before you can issue a redirect so that the company name is present in the URL, you could simply add it to the current request, for example in your controller

```
$this->request->params['company'] = 'acme';
```

From there on the generated URLs will contain the company name.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router::connect**

Comment: Awesome!! I am going to try this. Follow on question - how do I ensure even `echo $this->webroot` in Views have acme in them? If it is not possible I can just rewrite such statements with a Router::url - but I wanted to ask for the sake of completeness

Comment: @ChicagoSky Well, it would need to be changed manually as persistent parameters are reverse routing only, however doing so would mess up all asset URLs, not those URLs matching your routes, so this is probably not a good idea. For what purpose are you using `$this->webroot` in your views?

Comment: Just some legacy code - I've been postponing going back and rewriting these one. For instance, in some cases - I have AJAX calls which have a URL parameter set via a `<? echo $this->webroot.'Pages/view' ?>`

Comment: @ChicagoSky I see, yeah, you should definitely rewrite those to use `Router::url()`, the webroot property shouldn't be used in such a manner.

Comment: This worked fine - just a couple of pointers for others seeking similar information. I had to write full form `Router::url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'add'));` and not just the short form `Router::url('pages/add')` for this to work properly. Also, after the user logs in, I queried the database to find the relevant company name and attached that to array returned by `$this->Auth->loginRedirect()` - once this is done, then every page during the users active session will have the company name in the url.

Comment: last question - I have some Javascript files (.js) that I load in the main php. In many AJAX calls I have used echo webroot - I am trying to rewrite many of these to read `data-url` parameters. Is there any other easier / recommended approach?

Comment: @ChicagoSky That's hard to tell without seeing the whole picture. Generally using data attributes for passing values from the server to the client can be a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a $current_company variable in the **AppController.php** in the **beforeFilter** method:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $current_company = 'acme'; //just assigning a value, you can determine this variable in any way
    $this->set(compact('current_company'));
}
```

then, if your views, declare the company value in the links, like:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Link Name'),array('company' => $current_company,'controller' => 'YOUR_CONTOLLER', 'action' => 'YOUR_ACTION'), array('css' => 'my_style')); ?>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('company' => $current_company,'controller' => 'YOUR_CONTOLLER', 'action' => 'YOUR_ACTION')) ?>" class="my_style" id ="">Link Name</a>
```

or

```
echo Router::url(array('company' => $current_company,'controller' => 'YOUR_CONTOLLER', 'action' => 'YOUR_ACTION'))
```

Cake should automagically add the variable as prefix like /acme/YOUR_CONTOLLER/YOUR_ACTION

Comment: beforeRender() would suffice IMO to pass stuff down to the view.